# Deleting files from within SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, files, extended-stored-procedure

I've been using `xp_delete_file` to delete old backup files but I now an a need to delete files that are part of an application (as part of GDPR). As `xp_delete_file` only will only let you delete log or backup files, I thought I'd write my own in C#.

The trouble I'm finding now is extended stored procedures can only be rolled out to the master database. I'd rather contain this new stored procedure in my own user db so I can distribute via source control etc.

Does anyone know a way round this without using xp_cmdshell?

It could be done in PowerShell. I could even write the entire thing in C#. It however be really handy to be able to do it in T-SQL as well.

I am open to using a CLR stored procedure that invokes C# code. I was thinking of changing the stored procedure to a function if I can't deploy a stored procedure.

Comment: I've managed to solve it. The problem is you can only return an integer from the c# method. I was trying to return a string.

Comment: Andrew: Just FYI, I updated my answer to include some new info that was not available when you asked this question. I'm sure you are not in need of the info, but figured you might be interested in at least knowing it in case it comes up again in the future .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended Stored Procedures (XPs) have been deprecated as of the release of SQL Server 2005 and new projects should not be using that API.

This can be done easily via SQLCLR, and yes, you can return a string (or most datatypes) from a C# method. The only construct restricted to returning an INT is a Stored Procedure, and that holds true for both T-SQL and SQLCLR Stored Procedures.

You would use something along the lines of:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Stuff
{
  [SqlFunction(IsPrecise=true)]
  public static SqlString DeleteFile ([SqlFacet(MaxSize=500)] SqlString FilePath)
  {
    string _ReturnMessage = String.Empty;

    try
    {
      File.Delete(FilePath.Value);

      _ReturnMessage = "some text here";
    }
    catch (Exception _Error)
    {
      _ReturnMessage = _Error.Message;
    }
  }

  return new SqlString(_ReturnMessage);
}
```

When you create the T-SQL wrapper object, be sure to specify the `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` option so that it won't even both executing if a `NULL` is passed in (you should probably add additional validation to the method, such as returning if an empty string is passed in, etc):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DeleteFile
(
  @FilePath NVARCHAR(500)
)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
EXTERNAL NAME.... ;
```

Since the Assembly will need to be marked as `PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, please do not set the Database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`. Instead you should sign the Assembly, create the Asymmetric Key or Certificate in `[master]`, create a Login from that Asymmetric Key or Certificate, and then grant that Login the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission (if using SQL Server 2005 - 2016) or the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission (starting with SQL Server 2017).

For detailed instructions for doing this via a build process, you can try either of the two techniques I describe in the following blog posts (both work fully with SSDT or independently):

- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://SqlQuantumLeap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/)
- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 3: “CLR strict security” – Solution 2](https://SqlQuantumLeap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/)

Also consider supporting my Asymmetric Key suggestion which would eliminate most of the hassle of publishing signed Assemblies:

[Allow Asymmetric Key to be created from binary hex bytes string just like CREATE CERTIFICATE](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896978-allow-asymmetric-key-to-be-created-from-binary-hex)

OR, if you would rather not deal with any of this, there is a **File_Delete** function in the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=db_199187) SQLCLR library (that I wrote) that does this. It even returns a string, which is the error message if an error occurs, else is just an empty string. No way to have it pass back a custom string on success, though. Also, please note that while there is a Free version, the File System functions are only available in the Full version. But the security aspect would all be handled cleanly and properly, *and* there is even a T-SQL Stored Procedure, that exists in the same DB as the SQLCLR code, that will set up the `Asymmetric Key` and associated `Login` in `[master]` (which could help with deployments to new systems by not requiring a full install, as long as this Stored Procedure was deployed and executed prior to deploying any Assemblies (assuming an environment of SQL Server 2017)).

### UPDATE

SQL Server 2019 (which was not available at the time I posted this answer) introduces a new, undocumented system stored procedure, `xp_delete_files`, that is a bit more flexible than `xp_delete_file`. For more info, please see my answer here (also on DBA.SE):

[How is the new system stored procedure sys.xp_delete_files different from sys.xp_delete_file?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/258480/30859)