# How is the new system stored procedure sys.xp_delete_files different from sys.xp_delete_file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, extended-stored-procedure, file-system

SQL Server 2019 introduced a new (and undocumented) system stored procedure:

`sys.xp_delete_files`

What, exactly, does this new extended stored procedure do? How does it differ from `xp_delete_file` that has been around for years? Does it replace `xp_delete_file`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To start with, the older `xp_delete_file` (also undocumented) is quite limited:

1. It can only delete either backup (**.bak** / **.trn**) or report (??) files (I believe it actually scans the first part of them to verify the file "type"
2. It only deletes by file extension (i.e. not specific files, or whatever matches based on wildcards) *and* based on being older than the supplied date
3. It's picky and requires a trailing slash on the directory / folder
4. It can only delete files, not folders
5. It *can* recurse down through subfolders (ok, so this one is *not* a limitation)

For more info on it, please see:

- [How to Use xp_delete_file to Purge Old Backup Files](https://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdeletefile-to-purge-old.html)
- [SQL Server xp_delete_file not deleting files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/529770/577765)

---

The newer `sys.xp_delete_files` has the following syntax:

```sql
EXEC sys.xp_delete_files 'fileSpec.01' [, 'fileSpec.02' [, ...] ] ;
```

Notes:

1. File type / extension does not matter
2. Works with standard DOS wildcard characters:

   - `*` = zero or more of any character
   - `?` = exactly one of any character
3. Does *NOT* recurse through subdirectories (for deleting files) (this is the only "limitation")
4. Can specify multiple, fully-qualified path specifications, each being able to handle wildcards
5. Can remove entire non-empty subfolder structure!! (might need to run a few times to delete everything)
6. Must be a member of the `sysadmin` fixed Server Role in order to execute (use [Module Signing](https://modulesigning.info/) instead of adding application Login to `sysadmin` fixed Server Role; please see: [Safely and Easily Use High-Level Permissions Without Granting Them to Anyone: Server-level](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/02/15/safely-and-easily-use-high-level-permissions-without-granting-them-to-anyone-server-level/) )
7. Backported to SQL Server 2017 (possibly in CU18)

For complete details, please see my post:

[sys.xp_delete_files and ‘allow filesystem enumeration’: two new undocumented items in SQL Server 2019](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2020/01/26/sys-xp_delete_files-and-allow-filesystem-enumeration-two-new-undocumented-items-in-sql-server-2019/)